# How to provide methods outside the Angular Library - publishing to npm

Tags: angular

I created a simple application that needs several methods from the outside. I know that we export modules outside using public-api.ts but how to import any dependencies?

For example, I need to use the `getToken()` and `logout()` methods from `src/app/auth.service.ts` inside `projects/my-npm-project/src/lib/services/example.service.ts` how to do it?

Because when I add dependency in the traditional way (import * from ...) I get an error `'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.` when I run `ng build my-npm-project` ;/

```
Angular
|
|- projects
|   |_my-npm-project
|       |_src
|           |_lib
|               |_services
|                   |_example.service.ts
|                
|- src
    |_app
        |_auth.service.ts
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you can use the outside functions inside the Library. You may need to pass the values inside, or you may need to have an event emitted using @Output() and call the function from the main application folder, and pass value inside.

Comment: thanks for the answer :) but how can I pass these methods to deeply nested elements of the library?

Comment: I think, once it is passed into the library's main component, then maybe you can use Rxjs Subjects to emit the values and subscribe them from inner components using shared services. Since passing idata nto components using @Input() more than 2-3 layers is not advisable.